# React page-flip image add

Tags: reactjs

I am using react page-library. I want to add image. Css background-image and  and the path of the image is correct but the image is not added. How can I solve it?

```js
    const PageCover = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
        return (
            <div className="page page-cover" ref={ref} data-density="hard">
                <div className="page-content">
                    <div>{props.children}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });



    const Page = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
        return (
            <div className="page" ref={ref}>
                <div className="page-content">
                    <div className="page-image"></div>
                    <div className="page-text">{props.children}</div>
                    <div className="page-footer "><span className='px-2 py-2'>{props.number + 1}</span></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    });


    return (
        <div>
            <HTMLFlipBook
                width={550}
                height={505}
                size="stretch"
                minWidth={315}
                maxWidth={1000}
                minHeight={300}
                maxHeight={300}
                maxShadowOpacity={0.5}
                showCover={true}
                mobileScrollSupport={true}
                className="demo-book"
            >


                <PageCover className="">
                    <div className="w-full top-1/2 relative">
                        <div className="absolute top-1/2 flex items-center justify-center my-[50%] w-full bg-teal-400">
                            <h1 className='text-white text-center'>Hello World</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </PageCover>
                <Page number={1}>

                    <div className="w-full  my-2">
                        <p className='px-4'>Lorem ipsum... </p>

                        <div className="page-image" style={{backgroundImage: 'url("../../public/images/anadebeatriz.jpg")'}}>
                            
                        </div>

                    </div>


                </Page>
                <Page number={2}>Lorem ipsum...</Page>
                <PageCover></PageCover>

            </HTMLFlipBook>


        </div>
```

image appears in the project. The div named page-image needs to have an image inside. But it doesn't work even though the image is added.